# Rsync music files not connecting with Plex

Tags: terminal, cron, rsync, synology, plex

So I am testing an rsync (which will later become a cron) from my local (MACOS) music folder to my Plex music folder on my Synology NAS DS920+. My goal is to have a a system where my local files are uploaded to Plex so I can listen to them remotely because a lot of the files I own are from Bandcamp and are not available on Spotify, Youtube or Apple Music.

The rsync works and the files transfer successfully, yet when I tell Plex to 'Scan Library Files' it does not recognise the rsynced music files. However, when I add the same files manually and ask Plex to Scan it recognises them - it only refuses to recognise files transferred via rsync.

The command in the terminal is:

```
rsync -avu --delete ~/Music/PlexSync/Music/ Synology@999.999.9.999:/volume2/Plex/Music/
```

Why are the files being transferred but are not being recognised by Plex?

Comment: Compare the owner, group, and permissions between the files that Plex recognizes and those it does not - what differences do you see?

Comment: did you figure out what was going wrong with the media scanning?